# Recursion return undefined instead true

Tags: javascript, function, loops, if-statement, recursion

I am wonder why this function return undefined?
Any one may explain it for me?

```
function isEven(i) {
  if (i === 0 ) {
    return true;
  } else if (i == 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log(i);
    isEven(i - 2);
  }
}
console.log(isEven(6));
```

Comment: `return isEven(i - 2)`, missing `return`

Comment: `6 % 2 === 0` won't it be enough for checking a number is even?

Answer (score 7):

You aren't returning on the else statement. In JavaScript, all functions must return something, so if you forget to put a return statement in, it will return undefined.

```
} else {
    console.log(i);
    isEven(i - 2)
}
```

should be

```
 } else {
    console.log(i);
    return isEven(i - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify this a lot with:

```
function isEven(i){ return i%2===0; }
```

Comment: i know this methoed, but i am lerning recursion syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
//You should return value to expect output

function isEven(i) {
  if (i === 0 ) {
    return true;
  } else if (i == 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log(i);
    return isEven(i - 2);
  }
}

console.log(isEven(5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with more concise style with return at the end, because `else` is not necessary, because return ends the funtion continuity.

```js
function isEven(i) {
    if (i === 0 ) {
        return true;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    document.write(i + '<br>');
    return isEven(i - 2);
}
document.write(isEven(6));
```

A shortest for would be

```js
function isEven(i) {
    return !(i & 1);
}
document.write(isEven(5));
```

Comment: how this code works?
`function isEven(i) {
    return !(i & 1);
}
document.write(isEven(5));`

Comment: @meks, it uses the *bit operator and* (`&`). this works, because even numbers have one bit for 1, the most right bit. with `&`, you you get with uneven numbers 1 and for even numbers 0. that is oposite of the wanted, so here is the not operator `!` applied as well. please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)